# The image using eval() is not getting displayed in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, path, eval

In Laravel, I have written the below code in Blade.php. But the IMAGE won't get displayed. Can anyone please help?

```
<?php
eval("\$image_url = \"{{ url('public/uploads/trust/".$value.".jpg') }}\";");
?>

<img src="{{ $image_url }}" />
```

---

FYI, this is how the code looks from "debugger in browser" as below:-

```
<img src="{{ url('public/uploads/trust/logo.jpg') }}">
```

Comment: I think you don't need to append `public/` in front of the path (by Laravel's default folder structure). Do you see the image if you go to `your_url/public/uploads/trust/logo.jpg` in your browser?

Comment: Why do you need to use `eval`?

Comment: @Koeno, Thank you for your reply. Now, I have used the "Laravel's default folder structure". It worked :-)